# Android - Parse PHP json_encode to Java

Tags: java, php, android, json

```
String json_string_from_server = "{\"test1\":\"test1_value\",\"test2\":\"test2_value\"}";
```

how to loop the JSON and print all the keys and values.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html (2 seconds with google)

Comment: use `JSONObject` and `JSONArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply parse the Json string as below -

```
String json_string_from_server = "{\"test1\":\"test1_value\",\"test2\":\"test2_value\"}";

JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json_string_from_server);
String val_Test1 = jObj.getString("test1");
String val_Test2 = jObj.getString("test2");
```

case 2:

```
String json_string_from_server = "{ 
  "result" : [
    {\"test1\":\"test1_values_baru\", \"test2\":\"test2_values\"}, 
    {\"test1\":\"test‌​1_values\", \"test2\":\"test2_values\"}
  ]
}";

JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json_string_from_server);
JSONArray jResultArray = jObj.getJSONArray("result");
for(int i=0; i<jResultArray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jResultObj = jResultArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String val_Test1 = jResultObj.getString("test1");
    String val_Test2 = jResultObj.getString("test2");
}
```

Comment: this is perfectly working....thanks..

but i am wondering can we make it just loop all the values without inserting the key???

Comment: @Syamsoul Azrien: Not really coz to access a value u need its key. If its an array then the key is same and just value changed in that case looping can be done.

Comment: one more question.. sorry .. how to loop if JSON String is like this "[{\"test1\":\"test1_values_baru\",\"test2\":\"test2_values\"},{\"test1\":\"test1_values\",\"test2\":\"test2_values\"}]"

Comment: @Syamsoul Azrien: The string u've mentioned is not a valid JSON Array so I've corrected it and parsed. Check my edit :)

Comment: really nice! Thanks!

Comment: you know what, in your case 2 mentioned above, i just have my own solution without changing the JSON String i gave in this comment above.. i will share the solution in new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose jsonString is a variable in which you get all your json from php. You will need to iterate the array as follows:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(JsonString);
for(int i=0; i<= arr.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject obj = arr.get(i);
    obj.getString('test1');  // these are your strings
    obj.getString('test2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String json_string="[{\"test1\":\"test1_values_baru\",\"test2\":\"test2_values\"},{\"test1\":\"test‌​1_values\",\"test2\":\"test2_values\"}]";

JSONArray jResultArray = new JSONArray(json_string);
for(int i=0; i<jResultArray.length(); i++){
       JSONObject jResultObj = jResultArray.getJSONObject(i);
       String val_Test1 = jResultObj.getString("test1");
       String val_Test2 = jResultObj.getString("test2");
}
```

Comment: thats correct. Thought the json response r from sm webservices which u get in ur json_string.