# Insert json to mysql

Tags: android, mysql, json, sqlite

I am looking for a way to insert JSON to SQLite.
I have a php script that looks like this.

```
<?php 
require 'connection.php';

$var_fname      = "Mildred";
$var_password       = "ewan";
$var_email  = "saf";
$var_username = "enanpogi";
$var_lastname = "Mildred";
$var_aviaryName = "Mildred";
$var_location = "myLocation";

 $insert_stmt = $db->prepare(""
                . "INSERT INTO users"
                . "( fname, lname, email, password, username, aviary_name, location ) "
                . "VALUES( :name, :lastname, :email, :password, :username, :aviaryName, :location)" );
                // prepare and bind
                $insert_stmt->execute(array(
                    ':name'         => $var_fname,
                    ':lastname'     => $var_lastname,
                    ':password'     => $var_password,
                    ':email'        => $var_email,
                    ':username'     => $var_username,
                    ':aviaryName'   => $var_aviaryName,
                    ':location'     => $var_location
                ));
                $lastId = $db->lastInsertId();

                if ($insert_stmt){
                    echo "inserted</br>";
                    echo $lastId;
                    //get all information of newly inserted and make json encode to prepare for insertion in sqlite_array_query

                    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * '
                        . 'FROM users '
                        . 'WHERE id = :lastInsertedID ');
                    $stmt->bindParam(':lastInsertedID', $lastId);
                    $stmt->execute();

                    $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    if($results > 0 ){
                        //echo sizeof($results);
                        echo "</br>";
                        echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$results) );
                    }
                }
?>
```

when I run that script, I was able to get below result

```
{"user_data":{"id":"28","fname":"Mildred","lname":"Mildred","email":"saf","username":"enanpogi","aviary_name":"Mildred","password":"ewan","location":"myLocation","phonenumber":null,"active":null}}
```

I am not sure if it is JSON Object or JSON array..

Now, I need help to insert that JSON to SQLite in my Android JAVA app.

Comment: Remove `java` tag. It has nothing to do with java

Comment: There is no `</br>`. You should use `<br>` or `<br />`.

Comment: json_encode() gives you a string so if you want put it into sqlite db just put it as normal string

Comment: Do you want to put this data into SQLite as a simple string which is what `json_encode()` created for you OR do you want to put each individual fields in this JSON data structure into seperate columns in a SQLite table?

Comment: Should we assume that the code that calls this PHP script is a bit of Android Java code? If so look up how to convert a JSON String into an JAVA object i.e. `JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json_string_from_server);`

Comment: PHP's `json_encode()` will always create you an Object representation of both a PHP array and a PHP Object. After all the idea is you are passing this structure to an Object oriented receiver as the `J` in JSON stands for `Javascript`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I want to insert each individual fields in the JSON data into seprate columns in a SQLite.. and yes, I am trying to look how to convert and use that JSON String into a JAVA Object

Comment: Then see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727256/insert-json-to-mysql#comment62927361_37727256) on how to convert a JSON String into a JAVA Object in JAVA

Comment: @nospor Look closer, I think it does, purely based on the Android tag being there

Comment: This link might be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784394/android-parse-php-json-encode-to-java

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for the link. But I don't have idea what to put inside String json_string_from_server = "{ }" in android.. I don't know how to pull that json object in android..  what will be the parameter inside that "{}" in my case.. I mean... can I directly use "json_encode($results);" from my php? I am really new in android development..

Comment: @RiggsFolly 1) When I wrote my comment there were not tag `Android`. 2) Still I do not understand what is to do with java.

Comment: That will be what you are getting back from the call to the PHP script that does a `echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$results) );`

Answer (score 1):

Visit This Link :  [Json Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

- Paste Your Output as a Text in this Link.
- Click on Viewer.

You can find out that you got the json response or not. 
I check your result.it's in json format.You already got the json Object.

Now, Use json_encode($results) function gives you a string so you can easily insert it database.

Comment: No need in JSON `{}` indicates an Object `[]` indicates an Array. There is not much more to it than that!

Answer (score 0):

You will get JSON Object. json_encode will give you json object. But You will get json array when you use json_decode with second argument true.

Comment: But he is receiving the data in an Android JAVA app **I believe** so `json_decode()` is irrelevant